# python regex for complex list and integer combinations

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that I need to parse: Here is the sample string:

```
sample_string = "([0, 22, 23, 24, 25, 47, 59],36155), ([0, 1, 22, 23, 24, 25, 47, 59, 7],36154), ([0, 1, 22, 23, 24, 25, 47, 50, 59, 7],36153)"
```

I tried the following regex but do not seem to get it right:

```
\((\[[(\d)+][,?])+\]),(\d)+\)
```

The aim of the regex is easily access the list part of the tuple as well as the integer part of the tuple. The easiest would be to use ast.literal_eavl(sample_string) but was wondering why the above regex fails to parse it correctly?

Comment: If `sample_string` is a string, why is it not in quotes? There's multple issues with the regex, starting with the fact that it has unbalanced parentheses and disregards spaces, but why not just use `literal_eval` for this purpose?

Comment: sorry to have missed the quotes for the string.. I was curious as to why the regex did not work .. will try with the spaces in place. Thanks

Comment: Another issue is that it has unbalanced parentheses- it has one open but two that close. (When you say that something doesn't work, you should always show the traceback, preferably with a reproducible example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of your problems are as mentioned in the comments, including unbalanced parentheses and not accounting for whitespace.  Here is one regex that will extract what you need:

```
data = re.findall(r'\((\[(\d+,?\s?)+\]),\s*(\d+)\)', sample_string)

# data:
# [('[0, 22, 23, 24, 25, 47, 59]', '59', '36155'),
#  ('[0, 1, 22, 23, 24, 25, 47, 59, 7]', '7', '36154'),
#  ('[0, 1, 22, 23, 24, 25, 47, 50, 59, 7]', '7', '36153')]

for d in data:
    int_list_str = d[0]
    trailing_int_str = d[2]
```

Answer (score 5):

I would not recommend you to use regex here unless there is some compelling reasons.

Try the `ast` module

```
>>> import ast
>>> sample_string = "([0, 22, 23, 24, 25, 47, 59],36155), ([0, 1, 22, 23, 24, 25, 47, 59, 7],36154), ([0, 1, 22, 23, 24, 25, 47, 50, 59, 7],36153)"
>>> ast.literal_eval(sample_string)
(([0, 22, 23, 24, 25, 47, 59], 36155), ([0, 1, 22, 23, 24, 25, 47, 59, 7], 36154), ([0, 1, 22, 23, 24, 25, 47, 50, 59, 7], 36153))
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using the `split` and `eval` functions instead of regex?

```
list_of_lists = []
list_of_ints = []
tuple_list = sample_string.split(", ")
for tup in tuple_list:
    list_part,int_part = eval(tup)
    list_of_lists.append(list_part)
    list_of_ints.append(int_part)
```

EDIT: This will only work if you consistently have ", " between each pair of tuples and nowhere else (i.e., you need to remove the spaces after the commas in the lists and within the tuples). Since your data isn't formatted this way, this approach will fail.

Comment: Using `split` directly would fetch you this `['([0', '22', '23', '24', '25', '47', '59],36155)', '([0', '1', '22', '23', '24', '25', '47', '59', '7],36154)', '([0', '1', '22', '23', '24', '25', '47', '50', '59', '7],36153)']` which is not what you want

Comment: Oops, yeah, didn't notice that there are spaces after the commas within lists, too.

Answer (score -1):

`Regex` is a bad idea for the problem you're trying to solve. You would be able to capture only the last item using your match groups.

**For example:**

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> sample_string = r'([0, 22, 23, 24, 25, 47, 59],36155), ([0, 1, 22, 23, 24, 25, 47, 59, 7],36154), ([0, 1, 22, 23, 24, 25, 47, 50, 59, 7],36153)'
>>> 
>>> regexStr = r'(\(\[((\d+, )*\d+)\],\d+\), )*\(\[(\d+, )*\d+\],\d+\)'
>>> matchObj = re.match(regexStr, sample_string)
>>> print matchObj.groups()
('([0, 1, 22, 23, 24, 25, 47, 59, 7],36154), ', '0, 1, 22, 23, 24, 25, 47, 59, 7', '59, ', '59, ')
```

Use `eval` instead to get the list out of the string.

Comment: `eval` is even worse if you don't know what you're passing in